# Auth::user() not found after login laravel 6

Tags: laravel

In my application i've used separate controller for authenticating a user. Which is working fine. But i'm getting this error `Trying to get property 'role_id' of non-object` when i used Auth::user()->role_id. Which i understand that user is logged in, but unable to get user details using Auth::user(). Can anyone help me out! Here is my code.

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('Authentication/SignIn', array(
    'as' => 'signInForm',
    'uses' => 'AuthenticationController@signIn'
));
Route::post('Authentication/SignIn', array(
    'as' => 'signInAction',
    'uses' => 'AuthenticationController@signInAction'
));

Route::group(array(
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
    'prefix' => 'AuthenticatedUser'
), function () {
    Route::get('home','HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

app\Http\Controllers

```
public function signInAction(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->ajax()) {
            try {
                $loginBy = NULL;
                $loginByValue = $request->identifiers;

                if (is_numeric($loginByValue)) {
                    if (strlen($loginByValue) > 3 && substr($loginByValue, 0, 3)) {
                        $loginBy = 'phone_no';
                    } else {
                        $loginBy = 'user_id';
                    }
                } else if (filter_var($loginByValue, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $loginBy = 'email';
                } else {
                    $loginBy = 'username';
                }
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                echo $ex->getMessage();
            }

            $loginCredentials = array(
                $loginBy => $loginByValue,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'is_active' => 1
            );

            if (Auth::attempt($loginCredentials)) {

                return redirect()->intended(route('home::onlineInfo'));
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('signInForm')
                    ->with('errorMessage', 'The identifiers and password you entered don\'t match.')
                    ->withInput();
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Invalid request!');
        }
    }
```

app\Http\Controller\HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticatedUser;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use App\User;

use Auth;
use Validator;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');

        $this->data = array();
        $this->data['viewPath'] = 'AuthenticatedUser.Home.';
        $this->data['menuId'] = 16;
        $this->data['jsArray'][] = 'Home_OnlineInformation.js';

        if ($this->_hasPrivilegeToAccessTheMenu($this->data['menuId'], Auth::user()->role_id) == 0) {
            abort(404);
        };
    }
}
```

app\User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'tbl_users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

config/app.php

```
<?php

return [
    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'locale' => 'en',
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',
    'faker_locale' => 'en_US',
    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    'providers' => [

        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    'aliases' => [
        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: At first, you have to be sure that 'role_id' exits or not by debug dd(Auth::user())

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun Auth::user() is returning empty..

Comment: By mean, Your login functionality does not work properly.

Comment: change use Auth to use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Comment: Instead HomeController `__construct` use in serviceprovider .

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun It is working. Auth::attempt is also working. My guess is, there is something wrong with my auth middleware session.

Comment: @Qonvex620 i used that too... same problem

Comment: @RishiRaut can you be more specific!

Comment: check your user model maybe you did not extend it  to Authenticatable

Comment: @Qonvex620 i've updated my question and added my User.php model

Comment: can you put a guard while you attempt to login like this Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($loginCredentials)

Comment: I can't see the 'user_name' field in the User model.

Comment: make sure role_id exists in tbl_users table

Comment: @Qonvex620 i used Auth::guard('auth')->attempt($loginCredentials).. and it is giving me this error `Auth guard [auth] is not defined`

Comment: @Ranjeet it is exist

Comment: in your config > app.php check it there. Maybe you had missed something,

Comment: @NguyenHungThai that not the case i think,, yet i added that too.. But still having the save issue

Comment: @Qonvex620 Auth facade is there..

Comment: Are you sure the password stored in the database is encrypted?

Comment: please show  inside of your config > app.php

Comment: @Qonvex620 i've updated my question again..

Comment: Sorry, not the app, but the auth i mean.

Comment: Try `Auth::user()['role_id']` maybe that could do the trick since it's a non-object and it helped me out sometimes. I don't know if it would be the solution to this answer, can always try.

Comment: @Qonvex620 thanks for your time mate... But Ranjeet solution solved this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can't access middleware in controller's constructor 
because the middleware is not run yet, Try with this 

        class HomeController extends Controller {
        protected $user;
        public function __construct()
            {

                 $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

                    $this->user = Auth::user();

                    return $next($request);
                });
               date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');

                $this->data = array();
                $this->data['viewPath'] = 'AuthenticatedUser.Home.';
                $this->data['menuId'] = 16;
                $this->data['jsArray'][] = 'Home_OnlineInformation.js';

                if ($this->_hasPrivilegeToAccessTheMenu($this->data['menuId'], $this->user->role_id) == 0) {
                    abort(404);
                };
            }
         }
```